# How do I stop the timer from counting down when I switch to pause state?

Tags: java, time, game-development

I have a java game wherein there is a countdown timer from 60 secs. It works fine, but when I pause the game and return back to play state. the original time is now reduced because I found out that the timer still keeps running from the system no matter what gameState I'm in. How do I fix this?

I tried storing the remainingTime to a pauseTime variable whenever I switch states, and just subtract it and stuff. But my efforts seem to failed.

```
// GET ELAPSED TIME
        if(gp.gameState == gp.playState && remainingTime >= 0) {
            soundCounter--;
            elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            remainingTime = totalTime - elapsedTime;
            if(remainingTime <= 0) {
                remainingMilliseconds = 0;
                remainingSeconds = 0;
                remainingMinutes = 0;
                // GAME OVER
                gp.gameOver();
            } else {
                remainingMilliseconds = remainingTime % 1000;
                remainingSeconds = (remainingTime / 1000) % 60;
                remainingMinutes = (remainingTime / 1000) / 60;
            }
        }
        // DRAW TIMER
        timeString = String.format("%02d:%02d:%03d", remainingMinutes, remainingSeconds, remainingMilliseconds);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are calculating your elapsed time forever since the first `startTime`.

One of the solution would be to calculate a delta (difference) time between loop iterations.

Here some very primitive code that should get you started:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean paused = false;
    long lastRun = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsed = 0;

    System.out.println("Game start");

    while (true) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long delta = now - lastRun;

        if (!paused && delta > 0) {
            elapsed += delta;

            // Do game stuff
            System.out.println("Elapsed: " + elapsed);
            if (elapsed >= 5000) return;
            lastRun = now;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good Answer. Also, you could use `Instant`& `Duration`.

Comment: ohh thank you so much! also, do you think this process is a bad practice especially because my timer should reset back to 60 secs every level. do you think using the System.currentTimeMillis is efficient at countdowns? I'm also a beginner btw

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't really worry about efficiency at the level you are currently programming at. Computers nowadays are so fast, that it hinders your progress more to prematurely optimize, rather than helps it. Think about it - today's games track tens of thousands of objects at around 60 times per second. And hey, if my answer led you towards a decision, I would really appreciate if you marked it as solved :)